# Predicting LULC

Tags: molusce

I´m applying Molusce to predict LULC (produced from landsat data) from 1997-2007-2017 to 2017, 2027 and 2037, using Artificial Neural Network and Cellular Automata, but Kappa validations (under **Transition Potential Modelling and Validation fields**) are always around 30, as you can see in the image attached. I used variables like DEM, Slope, distance to roads and distance to streams.

How can I improve my data in order to achieve better validation results?

[image]